# Site page- watermarked background

Tags: web-part

How can I create a site page with a watermarked image as background.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS is a way to add an image as background to a SharePoint site-page. However, using CSS is *only* supported with **classic pages**, when you are using the **modern lay-out**, using CSS won't work for adding an image as a background.

Instead you can use supported way and navigate to *site-settings* -> *change the look* -> *select a theme* and on the page that appears, on the left-hand site, select a background image from your local computer.

When you are adding a background image this way, the image will also appear on the **modern pages**.

Answer (score 0):

Watermarks are easy to create using following CSS.

Add the following to the HEAD of your site page. Change the URL of background-image.

```
<style> 
    body { 
        background-image: url(image.gif); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed; 
    }
</style>
```